# React and Laravel: как отослать несколько файлов на сервер и сохранить их

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, fetch

У меня есть код на react. Там я формирую массив и отсылаю на сервер. Вот форма:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSend} encType="multipart/form-data">
                    <label>Item name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> this.handleInput('itemName',e)}/>

                    <label>Price</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> this.handleInput('price',e)}/>

                    <label>Count</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> this.handleInput('count',e)}/>

                    <label>Describe</label>
                    <textarea className="form-control" name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onChange={(e)=> this.handleInput('describe',e)}/>

                    <input type="file" multiple={true} capture={true} accept="image/*" onChange={(e)=> this.handleInput('files',e)}/>

                    <input type="submit" value="Add new"/>
                </form>
```

Код на react

```
 constructor()
{
    super();
    this.state={
            error: '',
            product:{
                    itemName: '',
                    price: 1,
                    count: 1,
                    describe: '',
                    files:[]
                },

        };
     this.handleSend = this.handleSend.bind(this);
     this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
}

handleInput(key, e)//формирую масив
{
    let prod = Object.assign({}, this.state.product);
    if(key === 'files')
    {
        prod[key] = e.target.files;
    } else {
        prod[key] = e.target.value;
    }
    this.setState({ product: prod });// запись масива в state
}

handleSend(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.product);

    fetch('api/items', {//Отправляю на сервер данные
        method: "post",
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
            "Accept" : "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.product)
    })
        .then(res => {return res.json()})
        .then(data =>{ console.log(data)})
        .catch((e) => {console.log('Failed with error: ', e);})
}
```

Ну и получаю масcив, его же отправляю на сервер для сохранения даных. Правильно ли я формирую масив?
[image: масив js]

Вот тут я сохраняю даные. Без цикла все работает, но вот с ним получаю ошибку.

```
 function addNewItem($req)
{
    $item = new Items();

    $item->itemName = $req->itemName;
    $item->count = $req->count;
    $item->price = $req->price;
    $item->describe = $req->describe;

    foreach ($req->files->file() as $file) {
        foreach ($file as $f) {
            $f->move(storage_path('images'), time().'_'.$f->getClientOriginalName());
        }
    }

    if($item->save())
    {
        return response()->json(['ok']);
    }
    return abort(500);
}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
{message: "Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag::file()", exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError", file: "W:\domains\reactLaravel\app\Items.php", line: 26, trace: Array(44)}
```

Не могу решить эту проблему. Нужно сохранить файлы на сервере в какой-то папке, без файлов все правильно записывается на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
foreach($request->only('files') as $files){
        foreach($files as $file) {

            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $size = $file->getClientSize();                
            $file->move($your/path);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Эти методы не работают, не понимаю почему
getClientOriginalExtension()
getClientSize()
move()

Их как бы нет, в среде (PhpStorm) дает предупреждение что метод не найден

Мне также интересно, как должен выглядеть этот объект $file -  как массив. Я нашел модуль, он сам генерирует массив файлов, но когда отправляю на сервер, то там что-то не то творится, не понимаю почему, а вот когда поворачиваю назад тот же массив, некоторые поля исчезают.

Comment: @PetroKok А вы указали тип запроса как addNewItem(Request $req) ?

Comment: Да, это функция и я передаю в параметр объект запроса, и там обрабатываю данные. Но есть одно но.
Вот масив на клиенте, это файл. И массив с префиксом File(2546921), но когда он приходит на сервер этот префикс исчезает, и массив выглядит просто как набор данных.

Comment: Вот так примерно на клиенте: 

files: Array(1)
0: File(2546921) {id: "files-1", extension: "jpg", sizeReadable: "3MB", preview: {…}, name: "convers.jpg", …}extension: "jpg".......

А вот на сервере: 

0:{id: "files-1", extension: "jpg", sizeReadable: "3MB", preview: {…}}

И когда использую методы для файла, то оно мне говорит, что это не файл, а просто массив, и я не понимаю как отправить правильно